# how do I clean ink out from inside the hp officejet 8600 printhead?

Tags: printer, cleaning, hp-officejet

I'm getting the dreaded "there is a problem with the ink system" on my hp officejet 8600. After watching a bunch of youtube videos I took it apart, and when I took the springs out (see picture) one of them has ink on it.

As this spring appears to be an electrical contact of some kind, I'm pretty sure there shouldn't be any ink on it. So in the picture the hole with no spring is where the ink is. How do I clean that out?

[image: this is the printhead with the front circuit board off]

Comment: “How do I clean that out?” - Isopropyl alcohol would be safer for PCB but it might not be safe for the ink.  It can definitely be used to clean PCBs

Comment: As Ramhound says, isopropyl - or perhaps easier, a can of contact cleaner, which is the same thing under pressure. In the end, though, it's leaking & needs to be replaced. Unless you do a lot of photo printing rather than office documents, I'd save your money & swap to a new laser instead. This never happens on lasers.

Comment: how do I get it in that little hole though?

Comment: How would you think? https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YtDQ.jpg

Comment: @Stu - Isopropyl alcohol will evaporate.  You could technically dunk the entire printer head in Isopropyl alcohol and it would evaporate quickly.  However, how effective that actually would be on ink, I cannot say since I would just replace the entire printer head.